# How do I pin to the windows taskbar a running version of Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

An issue that previous versions of Eclipse had is that if I pinned the exe to my Windows Taskbar, there would be two icons. As an alternative, I could pin the running EXE to the taskbar and it would work just fine.

Now that Eclipse Mars is out, this doesn't seem to be working anymore. Right clicking a running version of Mars does not bring up the "Pin to Taskbar" option. Is there something I'm missing or some other workaround to pin Mars to the windows taskbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this version, I had to add the -vm argument to the very top of my eclipse.ini file.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\[jdk version]\bin
```

This is strange as I've not had to do this before, however; it appears that others had to do this in the past with other versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse Mars, Windows 10 - did not help!

Comment: Was -vm the very first argument? Did you replace [jdk version] with the actual jdk version (make sure the path is valid)?